# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier not reusing cells

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` with a custom cell subclassing `UICollectionViewCell`. And in the code I have done the following:

```
 [self.collectionView_ registerClass:[AHPinterestCell class]
        forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"AHPinterestCell"];
```

this is what goes in my `cellForItem`

```
  AHPinterestCell *cell =
                (AHPinterestCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"AHPinterestCell"
                                                                             forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

however, it seems that it's not reusing the cell. In my collection view per screen it is showing about 9-10 cells, however when I do infinite scroll and then I call `insertItemsAtIndexPath` it calls the `initWithFrame` method on my custom cell, while it should probably reuse the cells I already have. Why is this?

**EDIT:**

I am adding a sample demo project that illustrates the problem, the link to the xcode project can be found [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19680269/Demo.zip). It's essentially doing an infinite scroll when you reach to the bottom, it just appends more stuff into it. But when you do so it's going to call the init method again.

Comment: @Rob I am calling registerClass in viewDidLoad

Comment: @Sang it should just init like 10 and then the rest when I scroll down it should never call init again because it's reusing what I already have

Comment: @Sang how sure are you that it will init when it becomes visible? So in my case I have a UICOllectionView that has 100 cells in it, yet 10 is shown at the screen at a time. So I assume only 10 init will be called and the rest will be reuse

Comment: @Rob I am not using xib or storyboard for this, there is no IBOutlet. I am subclassing UICollectionViewCell and then calling registerClass in view did load.

Comment: @Rob so when I call insertItemsAtIndexPath there are already some cells that scroll off the screen, and there's a lot of it that can be re-used. I thought initially that insertItemsAtIndexPath will ALWAYS create new cells.. but I suppose based on your explanation, it isn't the case

Comment: Correct. Admittedly, I'm using collection view I created in IB, but I find the `init` method for my `UICollectionViewCell` subclass is called in response to `insertItemsAtIndexPath` where it's supposed to (i.e. no cells have yet scrolled out of view), and not called where it's not supposed to (i.e. where it's reusing a cells that have scrolled off). And I'm not seeing any obvious problem in your code above. Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: @Rob I included a sample project if you want to take a look at it. It illustrates the problem.

Comment: @Rob yes, you can find it here https://github.com/chiahsien/UICollectionViewWaterfallLayout. Or I've actually edited the link so that it has the file missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, your code works fine. As expected, as cells scroll off the screen, they are eventually flagged as being available for reuse. And when you call `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier`, if there is a cell available for reuse, it will do so. If not, it creates one.

The time that you'll see a lot of cells being created is if you scroll fast or continually. But if you do short little scrolls, let go, pause, let the UI catch up and repeat, then you'll see very few cells being created.

I interpret this as meaning that iOS prioritizes the UI and the creation of new cells over the dequeuing of old cells, allowing their reuse. So if you flip quickly, it has trouble catching up and flagging old cells as available for reuse. This is probably not altogether bad, as this is probably what gives collection views such smooth flow. Flagging old cells for reuse is one of the less important things for iOS to do here. But clearly if memory is tight, this might be a problem.

By the way, if you put a `NSLog` in `dealloc`, too, you'll notice that when the UI finally catches up after doing a really fast scroll through the collection view, it clearly has some logic that says "gee, I've got more spare cells than I really need, I'm going to get rid of some of these." It's a pretty clever implementation, actually. A focus on speed, but with some memory optimizations that take place once the UI quiets down.

Comment: Rob, great observation.. so how do I make it so that it doesn't create cells when I insert new items? This is causing me memory issues because it spikes up.

Comment: @adit I suspect that if you use `UICollectionView`, you're kind of stuck with the built-in prioritization of UI over memory utilization. If you wanted to, you could always jettison `UICollectionView` and, instead, implement your own `UIScrollView` subclass with infinite scrolling that, in `scrollViewDidScroll`, prioritized the releasing of old cells over the creation of new cells. You'd just have to figure out how much `UICollectionView` functionality you'd want to reimplement yourself in your own `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, I have the same problem, but I thought of creating a category to give me the visible cell, if available.

```
// Header file UITableView+VisibleCell.h"
@interface UITableView (VisibleCell)
- (UITableViewCell*) visibleCellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end


// Implementation file UITableView+VisibleCell.m
#import "UITableView+VisibleCell.h"

@implementation UITableView (VisibleCell)

- (UITableViewCell*) visibleCellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    for( UITableViewCell* currentVisibleCell in self.visibleCells )
    {
        NSIndexPath* currentPath = [self indexPathForCell: currentVisibleCell ];
        if( [currentPath isEqual:(id) indexPath] )
        {
            return currentVisibleCell;
        }
    }    
    return nil;
}    
@end
```

You can also start by getting the visible cell then return cellForRowAtIndexPath instead of nil, its a question of style. (I needed this to retrieve a UITextField with a given tag in a given cell to make it becomeFIrstResponder, but cellForRowAtIndexPath kept re-allocating my cell, very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off accessibility from your device settings.
Its a bug .
I have got the same issue on my iPad mini.