# iOS: TableView with multiple Images per Row (SDWebImage)

Tags: ios, asynchronous, uitableview, sdwebimage

I am a bit desperated about my sectioned tableview. I use a custom UITableViewCell with 4 images like the one below:

[image: My custom UITableViewCell]

I try to load the images via SDWebImage for each cell.

The loading procedures are all done in my custom UITableViewCell - not in the UITableViewController. From the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` i just call `[cell setup]` which executes the following code in the current cell:

```
NSArray *imageViews = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.imageView1, self.imageView2, self.imageView3, self.imageView4, nil];

for (int i = 0; i < self.products.count; i++) {

    Product *currentProduct = [self.products objectAtIndex:i];
    UIImageView *currentImageView = [imageViews objectAtIndex:i];

    NSString *thumbURL = [[CommonCode getUnzippedDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:currentProduct.collectionFolderName];
    thumbURL = [thumbURL stringByAppendingPathComponent:thumbFolder];
    thumbURL = [thumbURL stringByAppendingPathComponent:currentProduct.product_photo];

    [currentImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

    [currentImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:thumbURL]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
}
```

The images are all stored in the documents directory and are not greater than max. 500Kb.

Problem:

My Problem is that when I scroll through my tableview it suddenly crashes and I don't know why. Enabling a symbolic breakpoint for all exceptions shows that it crashes because of one line in SDWebImage. Unfortunately there isn't a debugger output: (It crashes where the image is allocated)

```
UIImage *image = nil;
if ([imageOrData isKindOfClass:[NSData class]])
{
    image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:(NSData *)imageOrData];
}
```

I also tried to load images via `dispatch_asnyc` with a similar result. **Is it possible that it has something to do with concurrent file operations?**

Additionally I get Memory Warnings when I scroll very fast so that I have to clear the cache of SDWebImage. At the same time it stops at the code line in SDWebImage mentioned above.

I already searched the web for 2 days now and I didn't find something useful. I would be glad for some hints to fix this problem. If somebody needs additional data such as crash reports or something, just let me know and I will provide them quickly.

Comment: Are you using ARC? When the app crashes, what's the message (EXC_BAD_ACCESS, sig fault, etc.)? Did you try enabling zombies?

Comment: yeah I am using ARC. Unfortunately there is now message. I only get several Memory Warnings in my TableViewController until the app crashes. Additionally a symbolic breakpoint for all exceptions shows that this one line in SDWebImage makes troubles (it says: Thread 3: Stopped at breakpoint 0). The same occurs when I use an async queue instead of SDWebImage - it makes trouble when i want to allocate the image.

Comment: I think the reason why it stops when allocating the image is the low memory. But shouldn't SDWebImage handle this?

Comment: I agree with Bins Ich that the app is using too much memory.  Even though the image file size is 500k (which seems large for a thumbnail image), it's size in memory could be much larger (size in memory = width x height x bytes/pixel).  Suggest creating another version of the images being put in the table view that are the same size as the image views as a test.  I suspect you will not have the same issue.

Comment: What you're trying to do strikes me as a collection view.  Are you sure you want to use a sectioned table view?  Apple provides built in functionality for this now with Collection Views to efficiently manage dequeueing, scrolling, etc.

Comment: ok after generating thumbnails and saving them into documents directory - everything seems fine. and I thought max. 500kb file sizes are small enough and SDWebImage/iPad memory can handle them. Thumb file sizes are now between 4Kb - 8Kb.

Maybe a collection view is a smarter approach but I never used it before. When I have time I will get through it.

Comment: @sean Regard his UI, I'd agree with you (assuming that he's ok with only supporting iOS 6 and higher). But if Bins Ich's problem is memory consumption, while that's easily fixed for tableviews, collection views don't appear to be nearly as aggressive in terms of reusing cells, and thus it's easier to consume memory quickly. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14465288/1271826

Answer (score 0):

I have meet the same problem, But I solve it like below temporarily, but it *cause memory problem especially on iPhone 4s*

```
NSArray *arrImgs = cellModel.thumbnails_qqnews;
if (arrImgs.count > 0) {
    [self.imgView.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(__kindof UIImageView * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        [obj sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:arrImgs[idx]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholdImage"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
            if (image != nil) {
                obj.image = [UIImage cutImageWithTargetSize:[NEMulTiNewsCell getImgSize] image:image];
            }
        }];
    }];
}
```

I think multi images download is illogical，but the method i think is download multi images then draw multi images in one image then display, but it may create large number line of code.